# PyQt type() and itemAt() return different things

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to set up unit tests for my PyQt app, and I ran into an unexpected situation.

Basically, the type of item returned from layout.itemAt() is different from the item that was added to the layout, and I'm curious why.

Here's my example code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        print(type(self.table))
        print(type(self.layout.itemAt(0)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When this is run, `type(self.table)` returns `<class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidget'>` as expected, but `type(self.layout.itemAt(0))` -- which is still the table item -- returns `<class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidgetItem'>`, and I can't figue out why they would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes that inherit [`QLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html) as [`QBoxLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html), [`QGridLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html), [`QFormLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html) and [`QStackedLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html) have as their main element the [`QLayoutItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#QLayoutItem)(in your case [`QWidgetItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetitem.html)) which is a class that can handle the geometry of other `QLayout`s and `QWidget`s, and that is the object that is being returned with the method [`itemAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#itemAt).

If you want to get the widget you must use the [`widget()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#widget) method of the [`QLayoutItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        assert(self.table == self.layout.itemAt(0).widget())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Oh I see, got it. Thank you so much. Next time I'll dive deeper into the docs before asking!

Answer (score 0):

That object type is an intermediate between the widget and the layout that is created by the layout when you add an item (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetitem.html)). Use `self.layout.itemAt(0).widget()` to get the original widget!